# Can you help me understand why the below code on linked list gives me a segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am new to programming and took C to begin with, I was coding this linked list problem. What I thought I did is,

- head pointer as global to access it from anywhere and set it to null initially
- in the insert code, create new pointer of the same type and allocate memory and give it the inserted data. Point head pointer to this first inserted data current
- for next insertions pass in the head and iterate over till the end and make the next of the last node point the current one and current to null
- Similarly for display pass in the head and iterate till the end and print

What am I missing here can someone help me why am I getting segmentation fault error for the **second input** and how to correct it?
Should there be any changes to display function as well?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void insert(int data_add);
void display();
struct list
{
  int data;
  struct list *next;
} *head = NULL;

int main()
{
  int data_add,n;
  while(1)
  {

    printf("\n\n1.Add\n2.Display\n3.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    switch(n)
    {
      case 1: printf("\nEnter the element to add ");
              scanf("%d",&data_add);
              insert(data_add);
              break;
      case 2: printf("The nos are: ");
              display();
              break;
      case 3: exit(1);
      break;
      default: printf("\nOpen your eyes");
    }
  }
}

void insert(int add)
{
  struct list *current,*temp;
  current  = (struct list*) malloc (sizeof(struct list));
  current->data = add;
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = current;
    current->next = NULL;
  }
  else
    {
      for(temp = head; temp!=NULL;temp = temp->next);
      temp->next = current;
      current->next = NULL;

    }
}

void display()
{
  struct list *current;
  current = head;
  while(current!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d",current->data);
    current = current->next;
}
}
```

Comment: In `insert()`, after your `for` loop to find the end of the list, `temp` is `NULL`... it goes one iteration too far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this code:

```
  for(temp = head; temp!=NULL;temp = temp->next);
  temp->next = current;
```

So, your condition for ending the loop is `temp != NULL` Then, what is `temp` after the loop ran? `NULL`, of course!

Your stop-condition needs to be `temp->next != NULL`.

On a side note: It's time to learn using a debugger. With enough experience, you spot such things just by looking at code, but there are more complicated ways to fail as well ;) With a debugger, you would have found that issue immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well as the advice I will learn how to use the debugger!

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do:

```
NULL->next = current
```

Instead, in your for loop you should be checking for

```
temp->next != NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the code below:

```
else{
  for(temp = head; temp!=NULL;temp = temp->next);
    temp->next = current;
    current->next = NULL;
}
```

when the for loop breaks, **temp** becomes NULL so you shouldn't access **temp->next**

you can change your code as below:

```
void insert(int add)
{
  struct list *current,*temp;
  current  = (struct list*) malloc (sizeof(struct list));
  current->data = add;
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = current;
    current->next = NULL;
  }
  else
    {
      //for(temp = head; temp!=NULL;temp = temp->next);
      temp = head;
      while(true){
        if(temp->next == NULL)
          break;
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      temp->next = current;
      current->next = NULL;

    }
}
```